Jetpack Compose LazyRow with adaptive item widths
I have the following jetpack code snippet, my problem is, that if there are not enough items in the LazyRow to make it scrollable, all items should take up equal space like "weight(1f)", but otherwise they should only take up as much width as the content requires and make the LazyRow scroll. The items.size can be changed by the user dynamically on the fly.
Row {
    Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
       Column(
             modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min),
             horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
             ) {
               Text(
                   modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                   text = "text1",
                   style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                   textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                   fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                   )
               HorizontalDivider()
               Text(
                   modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                   text = "text2",
                   style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                   textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                   fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                   )
                }
                VerticalDivider()
      }
      LazyRow(
             modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
             ) {
               repeat(items.size) { index ->
                   item {
                         Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
                             Column(
                                   modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min),
                                   horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                                   ) {
                                     Text(
                                        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                                        text = "textx" + index,
                                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                                        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                                        )
                                     HorizontalDivider()
                                     Text(
                                         modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                                         text = "texty" + index,
                                         style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                                         textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                                         fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                                         )
                                     }
                                     VerticalDivider()
                           }
                     }
             }
       }
       Row(modifier = Modifier.height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
           VerticalDivider()
           Column(
                modifier = Modifier.width(IntrinsicSize.Min),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
                ) {
                  Text(
                      modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                      text = "text3",
                      style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                      textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                      fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                      )
                  HorizontalDivider()
                  Text(
                      modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                      text = "text4",
                      style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                      textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
                      fontWeight = FontWeight.Light,
                      )
                 }
            }
    }

